# Changing sepecific text in a specific line in text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-2.0

here is the text line in aspx file I want to change

```
<center><body link=blue vlink=purple class=xl65 onload="processData();"><form id="mainform"
 action="http://localhost/XLEZ/DataHandler/Submit.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-
data"><input type="hidden" id="hid_extra" name="hid_extra" 
value="Machine_Inspection_20140807162226.xlsx||Machine_Inspection||Excavator 
Inspection||Excavator Inspection|Forklift Inspection|Tractor Inspection"/>
```

my code finds this line, I want to change the action of form in this line,

Here is my code which basically changes the whole line but i just want to change the specific text

```
String Form_action ="http://\" + Request.Url.Authority+\"/XLEZ/DataHandler/Submit.aspx\"";

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {

                            if (line.Contains("form id=\"mainform\""))
                            {
                                index = count;
                            }
                            count++;
                        }
                        sr.Dispose();
                    }
                    if (index != 0)
                    {
                        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(selected_path);
                        lines[index] = Form_action ;
                        File.WriteAllLines(selected_path, lines);
                    }
```

but this replaces the whole line with action, I just want to change the action in this line

Comment: Why don't you use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: @HassanNisar Using visual studio 2008 with DOT NET Framework 2.0

Comment: Yes dlls are available for .Net 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code this line of code obviously replaces the whole line of HTML code:

```
lines[index] = Form_action ;
```

You need to replace a part of the string in this line. You could do the following for example:

```
String Form_action ="http://\" + Request.Url.Authority+\"/XLEZ/DataHandler/Submit.aspx\"";

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                        if (line.Contains("form id=\"mainform\""))
                        {
                            index = count;
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    sr.Dispose();
                }
                if (index != 0)
                {
                    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(selected_path);
                    int start = lines[index].IndexOf("action");
                    string newLine = lines[index].Substring(0, start + 8) + Form_action + " " + lines[index].Substring(lines[index].IndexOf("method"));
                    lines[index] = newLine;
                    File.WriteAllLines(selected_path, lines);
                }
```

Your "Form_Action" variable will not hold the right value, since you escaped the " before you use the Request object. You should take a look at this.

Adjusted Form-Action creation:

```
String Form_action ="http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/XLEZ/DataHandler/Submit.aspx\"";
```

Comment: how can i find the indexOf "/XLEZ" in this line, like you have done with "action" & "method" in your answer

Comment: I just want to put "+<%=Request.Url.Authority %>+" after htp//: and before /XLEZ to get current IP address...

Comment: You can just find it like the other strings with 'lines[index].IndexOf("XLEZ")' or you just adjust the creation of the Form_action string. I'll update my answer with the adjusted version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a much simpler way using Regular Expressions:

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(".*form id=\"mainform\".* action=\"(.+?)\" .*");

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(selected_path);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        Match match = regex.Match(line);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            string toReplace = match.Groups[1].Value;
            lines[count] = lines[count].Replace(toReplace, Form_action);
        }
        count++;
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(selected_path, lines);
```